# Prevent vscode-jest-tests from opening new terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs, vscode-debugger

I am using vscode-jest and the "debug" code lens to run individual tests. However, when running a test like this it spawns a new terminal every time. How can I prevent this by modifying the launch configuration in the launch.json file?

For reference, here is my launch.json:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "name": "vscode-jest-tests",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--runInBand"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/data-utils/",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/data-utils/node_modules/jest/bin/jest"
        }
    ]
}
```